# Updating a calculated field in the parent record after submitting/updating child record in a modal dialogue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of an issue updating a calculated field of the parent form when submitting/updating a child record with a bootstrap 3 modal dialogue, from within the parent form.

I have this function in `parent.js` file:

```
function update_lineitems_subtotal() {
  var qid = $j('[name=SelectedID]').val();
  if (!isNaN(qid)) {
    $j.ajax({
      url: 'hooks/ajax_quote_subtotal.php',
      data: {qid: qid},
      success: function(data) {
        $j('#LineItemsSubtotal').val(data);
        $j('#Shipping').keyup();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $j('#LineItemsSubtotal').val('0');
    $j('#Shipping').keyup();
  }
};
```

And this is the `ajax_quote_subtotal.php` that runs with the ajax call above:

```
<?php
    $currDir = dirname(__FILE__)  .  '/..';
    include("$currDir/defaultLang.php");
    include("$currDir/language.php");
    include("$currDir/lib.php");

    /* grant access to users with access to quotations table */
    $od_from = get_sql_from('quotations');
    if(!$od_from){
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "You do not have permission to access this page. If this behaviour is unexpected, please contact the system administrator";
        exit;
    }

    $qid = intval($_REQUEST['qid']);
    if(!qid) exit;

    $parts_subtotal = sqlValue("select sum(Subtotal) from product_line_items where QuotationID='{$qid}' ");
    $service_subtotal = sqlValue("select sum(Subtotal) from service_line_items where QuotationID='{$qid}' ");

    $subtotal = $parts_subtotal + $service_subtotal;
    sql("update quotations set LineItemsSubtotal='{$subtotal}' where QuotationID='{$qid}' ", $eo);

    echo number_format($subtotal, 2);

?>
```

This is the function from `child.js` that closes the modal dialogue when the form is submitted and runs the `update_lineitems_subtotal` function from the `parent.js`

```
if($j('input[name=Embedded]').val()==1){
    $j('form').submit(function(){
        window.parent.jQuery('.modal').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
            parent.update_lineitems_subtotal();
        }, 100);

    })
}
```

This works as long as I do not remove `setTimeout`,however I do not feel like it is a good solution.
If the `setTiemout` is removed the record is created but it looks like the function runs before the child record is submitted, so the value of the subtotal field in the parent excludes the latest added record.

I have also tried this:

```
if($j('input[name=Embedded]').val()==1){
    $j('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     this.submit();
     window.parent.jQuery('.modal').modal('hide');
     parent.update_lineitems_subtotal();
   })
}
```

This had similar results in Chrome and refused to even create a child record in Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I am new to this, if you have time to explain the code you may suggest it would be greatly appreciated.